# Create a facebook event using javascript and facebook connect

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm building a site that uses facebook connect. Is it possible to create facebook events on the site and invite friends and publish this event on facebook just using javascript?

I've had a look on developers.facebook.com, but can't work out if the Graph API is what I'm looking for or if that is only open to facebook apps.

Comment: I dont think that you can create event of facebook at your site. however you can publish any thing to your site and you can invite your friends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`create_event` is no longer available from v2.0 and hence it's no longer possible to create events through the API. [ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)

---

Here you go:
Required [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions): `create_event`

JS to create an [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event):

```
$('#create-event').click(function() {
    FB.api('/me/events','post',{name:"JS-SDK Event",start_time:1272718027,location:"Here"},function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.id);
    });
    return false;
});
```

JS to invite friends, using the [`invited`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited) connection:

```
$('#invite-event').click(function() {
    FB.api('/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3','post',function(resp) {
        console.log(resp); // should return true
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't want to make an application, I want to create some script that will run on my site which is external to facebook. Users who log in using Connect should be able to begin creating an event on my site at the very least, even if they have to eventually transfer to facebook to complete the event and invite guests.

Comment: @gpr: you need to create an application. this is not possible without it!

Comment: hey even I was looking for the same thing, but I did not get how to add permissions using JS-SDK. I am novice to fb applications development

Comment: @JeevanDongre [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) you'll see an example of how you do it.

Comment: @ifaour hi so I cant invite my friends to an app event?

Comment: It is not possible to create FB events via API anymore. Probably some SPAM protection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Login(){
FB.login(function(response) {


       if (response.authResponse) {
         var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
       //  alert('Access Token = '+ access_token);
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert('welcome ' + response.name + '.');


        FB.api('/me/events','post',{ 
            name: 'TEST',
            start_time: '2013-06-03T15:00:00-0700',
            end_time:   '2013-06-03T19:00:00-0700',
            description:'Birthday party',
            location:'Mumbai',
            privacy_type:"OPEN",

        },

        function(response) {

             // alert(response.name);

              console.log(response);

              alert(response.id);
              eventid(response.id);

        });
         });
       } else {
          // callAjaxlogout();



        //alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     },{scope: 'create_event,user_events'});

}
```

HTML:

```
/*required permissions:create_event,user_events;*/

<button id="login" name="login" onclick="Login()">Login</button>
```